# Calculator: I can't seem to use isPressed correctly

Tags: java

I tried to make a calculator but it doesn't work. it gets stuck to the point where it has to do the calculation ( = button). I tried using getModel().isPressed() to check whether the button was clicked or not but it doesn't work... Any help?

Here is the whole code

> import javax.swing.*; import java.awt.*; import
> java.awt.event.ActionEvent; import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
>
> ```
> public class Calc {
>
>     private static JFrame fr = new JFrame();
>     private static JPanel jp = new JPanel();
>     private static JTextField txt = new JTextField();
>     private static JButton[] b = new JButton[16];
>     private static String daText ="";
>     private static float[] NUM = new float[5];
>     private static boolean b10 , b11 ,b12 ,b13 ;
>     private static float sum;
>
>     public static void GUI(){
>
>         fr.setSize(365,310);
>         fr.setTitle("Calculator");
>         fr.setResizable(false);
>         fr.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
>
>         jp.setBounds(1,1,301,301);
>         jp.setLayout(null);
>         jp.setVisible(true);
>         fr.add(jp);
>
>         txt.setBounds(10,10,330,30);
>         txt.setEditable(false);
>         txt.setBackground(new Color(0xFFEB85));
>         txt.setText("");
>         jp.add(txt);
>
>         b[0] = new JButton();
>         b[0].setBounds(10,45, 50,50);
>         b[0].setFocusable(false);
>         b[0].setBackground(new Color(0x80FF80));
>         b[0].setText("1");
>         b[0].addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
>             @Override
>             public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
>                 daText += "1";
>                 txt.setText(daText);
>             }
>         });
>         jp.add(b[0]);
>
>         b[1] = new JButton();
>         b[1].setBounds(65,45,50,50);
>         b[1].setFocusable(false);
>         b[1].setBackground(new Color(0x80FF80));
>         b[1].setText("2");
>         b[1].addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
>             @Override
>             public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
>                 daText += "2";
>                 txt.setText(daText);
>             }
>         });
>         jp.add(b[1]);
>
>         b[2] = new JButton();
>         b[2].setBounds(120,45,50,50);
>         b[2].setFocusable(false);
>         b[2].setBackground(new Color(0x80FF80));
>         b[2].setText("3");
>         b[2].addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
>             @Override
>             public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
>                 daText += "3";
>                 txt.setText(daText);
>             }
>         });
>         jp.add(b[2]);
>
>         b[3] = new JButton();
>         b[3].setBounds(10,100,50,50);
>         b[3].setFocusable(false);
>         b[3].setBackground(new Color(0x80FF80));
>         b[3].setText("4");
>         b[3].addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
>             @Override
>             public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
>                 daText += "4";
>                 txt.setText(daText);
>             }
>         });
>         jp.add(b[3]);
>
>         b[4] = new JButton();
>         b[4].setBounds(65,100,50,50);
>         b[4].setFocusable(false);
>         b[4].setBackground(new Color(0x80FF80));
>         b[4].setText("5");
>         b[4].addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
>             @Override
>             public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
>                 daText += "5";
>                 txt.setText(daText);
>             }
>         });
>         jp.add(b[4]);
>
>         b[5] = new JButton();
>         b[5].setBounds(120,100,50,50);
>         b[5].setFocusable(false);
>         b[5].setBackground(new Color(0x80FF80));
>         b[5].setText("6");
>         b[5].addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
>             @Override
>             public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
>                 daText += "6";
>                 txt.setText(daText);
>             }
>         });
>         jp.add(b[5]);
>
>         b[6] = new JButton();
>         b[6].setBounds(10,155,50,50);
>         b[6].setFocusable(false);
>         b[6].setBackground(new Color(0x80FF80));
>         b[6].setText("7");
>         b[6].addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
>             @Override
>             public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
>                 daText += "7";
>                 txt.setText(daText);
>             }
>         });
>         jp.add(b[6]);
>         
>         b[7] = new JButton();
>         b[7].setBounds(65,155,50,50);
>         b[7].setFocusable(false);
>         b[7].setBackground(new Color(0x80FF80));
>         b[7].setText("8");
>         b[7].addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
>             @Override
>             public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
>                 daText += "8";
>                 txt.setText(daText);
>             }
>         });
>         jp.add(b[7]);
>
>         b[8] = new JButton();
>         b[8].setBounds(120,155,50,50);
>         b[8].setFocusable(false);
>         b[8].setBackground(new Color(0x80FF80));
>         b[8].setText("9");
>         b[8].addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
>             @Override
>             public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
>                 daText += "9";
>                 txt.setText(daText);
>             }
>         });
>         jp.add(b[8]);
>
>         b[9] = new JButton();
>         b[9].setBounds(65,210,50,50);
>         b[9].setFocusable(false);
>         b[9].setBackground(new Color(0x80FF80));
>         b[9].setText("0");
>         b[9].addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
>             @Override
>             public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
>                 daText += "0";
>                 txt.setText(daText);
>             }
>         });
>         jp.add(b[9]);
>
>         b[10] = new JButton();
>         b[10].setBounds(180,45,50,50);
>         b[10].setFocusable(false);
>         b[10].setBackground(new Color(0xFF8080));
>         b[10].setText("+");
>         b[10].addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
>             @Override
>             public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
>                 b10 = true;
>                 NUM[0] = 0;
>                 NUM[1] = 0;
>                 NUM[2] = 0;
>                 NUM[3] = 0;
>                 NUM[4] = 0;
>                 NUM[0] = Float.valueOf(txt.getText());
>                 System.out.println(NUM[0] + " - - This is da NUM[0]");
>                 daText ="";
>                 txt.setText(daText);
>                 b[10].removeActionListener(this);
>                 b[15].addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
>                     @Override
>                     public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
>                         daText += ".";
>                         txt.setText(daText);
>                         if(txt.getText().contains(".")){
>                             b[15].removeActionListener(this);
>                         }
>                     }
>                 });
>             }
>         });
>         jp.add(b[10]);
>
>         b[11] = new JButton();
>         b[11].setBounds(235,45,50,50);
>         b[11].setFocusable(false);
>         b[11].setBackground(new Color(0xFF8080));
>         b[11].setText("-");
>         b[11].addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
>             @Override
>             public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
>                 b11 = true;
>                 NUM[0] = 0;
>                 NUM[1] = 0;
>                 NUM[2] = 0;
>                 NUM[3] = 0;
>                 NUM[4] = 0;
>                 NUM[0] = Float.valueOf(txt.getText());
>                 daText = "";
>                 txt.setText(daText);
>                 b[15].addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
>                     @Override
>                     public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
>                         daText += ".";
>                         txt.setText(daText);
>                         if(txt.getText().contains(".")){
>                             b[15].removeActionListener(this);
>                         }
>                     }
>                 });
>             }
>         });
>         jp.add(b[11]);
>
>         b[12] = new JButton();
>         b[12].setBounds(180,100,50,50);
>         b[12].setFocusable(false);
>         b[12].setBackground(new Color(0xFF8080));
>         b[12].setText("/");
>         b[12].addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
>             @Override
>             public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
>                 b12 = true;
>                 NUM[0] = 1;
>                 NUM[1] = 1;
>                 NUM[2] = 1;
>                 NUM[3] = 1;
>                 NUM[4] = 1;
>                 NUM[0] = Float.valueOf(txt.getText());
>                 System.out.println(NUM[0] + " -- This is the NUM[0]");
>                 daText ="";
>                 txt.setText("");
>                 b[15].addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
>                     @Override
>                     public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
>                         daText += ".";
>                         txt.setText(daText);
>                         if(txt.getText().contains(".")){
>                             b[15].removeActionListener(this);
>                         }
>                     }
>                 });
>             }
>         });
>         jp.add(b[12]);
>
>         b[13] = new JButton();
>         b[13].setBounds(235,100,50,50);
>         b[13].setFocusable(false);
>         b[13].setBackground(new Color(0xFF8080));
>         b[13].setText("*");
>         b[13].addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
>             @Override
>             public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
>                 NUM[0] = 1;
>                 NUM[1] = 1;
>                 NUM[2] = 1;
>                 NUM[3] = 1;
>                 NUM[4] = 1;
>                 b13 = true;
>                 NUM[0] = Float.valueOf(txt.getText());
>                 System.out.println(NUM[0] + " -- This is the NUM[0]");
>                 daText ="";
>                 txt.setText("");
>                 b[15].addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
>                     @Override
>                     public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
>                         daText += ".";
>                         txt.setText(daText);
>                         if(txt.getText().contains(".")){
>                             b[15].removeActionListener(this);
>                         }
>                     }
>                 });
>             }
>         });
>         jp.add(b[13]);
>
>         b[14] = new JButton();
>         b[14].setBounds(290,45,50,105);
>         b[14].setFocusable(false);
>         b[14].setBackground(new Color(0xFF8080));
>         b[14].setText("=");                                // I cannot check if any button is clicked or not...
>         b[14].addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
>                 public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
>
>                     NUM[1] = Float.parseFloat(txt.getText());
>                     System.out.println(NUM[1] + " - - NUM[1]");
>                     if(b[10].getModel().isPressed()){
>                         sum = NUM[0] + NUM[1] + NUM[2] + NUM[3] + NUM[4];
>                         txt.setText(String.valueOf(sum));
>                     }
>                     if(b[11].getModel().isPressed()){
>                         sum = NUM[0] - NUM[1] - NUM[2] - NUM[3] - NUM[4];
>                         txt.setText(String.valueOf(sum));
>                     }
>                     if(b[12].getModel().isPressed()){
>                         sum = NUM[0] / NUM[1] / NUM[2] / NUM[3] / NUM[4];
>                         txt.setText(String.valueOf(sum));
>                     }
>                     if(b[13].getModel().isPressed()){
>                         sum = NUM[0] * NUM[1] * NUM[2] * NUM[3] * NUM[4];
>                         txt.setText(String.valueOf(sum));
>                     }
>             }});
>
>         jp.add(b[14]);
>
>         b[15] = new JButton();
>         b[15].setBounds(180,155,50,50);
>         b[13].setFocusable(false);
>         b[15].setBackground(new Color(0x92FFE6));
>         b[15].setText(".");
>         b[15].addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
>             @Override
>             public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
>                 daText += ".";
>                 txt.setText(daText);
>                 if(txt.getText().contains(".")){
>                     b[15].removeActionListener(this);
>                 }
>             }
>         });
>         jp.add(b[15]);
>         
>         
>         fr.setVisible(true);
>     }
>
>     public static void main(String[] args) {
>         GUI();
>     }
> }
> ```

Here is the = button

```
    >    b[14] = new JButton();
    >     b[14].setBounds(290,45,50,105);
    >     b[13].setFocusable(false);
    >     b[14].setBackground(new Color(0xFF8080));
    >     b[14].setText("=");        

                        // I cannot check if any button is clicked or not...
>     b[14].addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
>             public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
> 
>                 NUM[1] = Float.parseFloat(txt.getText());
>                 System.out.println(NUM[1] + " - - NUM[1]");
>                 if(b[10].getModel().isPressed()){
>                     sum = NUM[0] + NUM[1] + NUM[2] + NUM[3] + NUM[4];
>                     txt.setText(String.valueOf(sum));
>                 }
>                 if(b[11].getModel().isPressed()){
>                     sum = NUM[0] - NUM[1] - NUM[2] - NUM[3] - NUM[4];
>                     txt.setText(String.valueOf(sum));
>                 }
>                 if(b[12].getModel().isPressed()){
>                     sum = NUM[0] / NUM[1] / NUM[2] / NUM[3] / NUM[4];
>                     txt.setText(String.valueOf(sum));
>                 }
>                 if(b[13].getModel().isPressed()){
>                     sum = NUM[0] * NUM[1] * NUM[2] * NUM[3] * NUM[4];
>                     txt.setText(String.valueOf(sum));
>                 }
>         }});
> 
>     jp.add(b[14]);
```

Comment: Please get rid of all the >s and just use ``` instead.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Have you tried using java fx instead? With Scenebuildee its very easy to build guis and set up methods.
I  didn't use java awt much maybe it is "isPressed()=true" or

```
ActionListener actionListener_Pause_Start = new ActionListener()
       {
           @Override
           public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent actionEvent)
           {
```